# How to share Bearer tokens created with Microsoft.Owin.Security?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I'm using ASP.NET Identity token authentication in several separate OWIN Web Api 2 services and want to consolidate the services to a single server. Each currently has their own /token end point. My vision is to have a single /token end point for all of them, but this means sharing auth tokens.

In ASP.NET Forms Authentication, the auth cookie could be shared by using the same machine key value in any application that participated in the sharing, so I'm thinkng it a similar mechanism.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could use client_id when calling the "/token" endpoint. Then call the validation logic you need based on that value.